# Find, count and sort all audio files. ALAC (M4A) files

Tags: shell-script, find, audio, sort

I'm putting a script together to sort a very large music collection. It's approx 22000 albums, a mixture of FLAC, WAV, AIFF, M4A (AAC & ALAC).

So far, I can sort by file type and get a total size of each type.

```
ftypes=$(find . -type f | grep -iE ".*\.[a-zA-Z0-9]*$" | sed -e 's/.*\(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]*\)$/\1/' | sort -f | uniq -i)

for ft in $ftypes
do
echo -n "$ft "
find . -name "*${ft}" -print0 | xargs -0 du -hc | grep total | awk '{print $1}'
done
```

I'd like to edit this to get the number of files by file type as well as the total size.

Now, the M4A files could be either AAC or ALAC, and I'd like to know how many of each.

I can find and print a list of ALAC files with

```
find . -name \*.m4a | while read file; do avprobe "$file" 2>&1 | grep -q 'Audio: alac' && echo "$file"; done
```

but I'm lost on how to get the total file count and size, instead of a list of file names, and combine it all into one script.

Basically, I'd like to output:

- List of file types
- Number of files by filetype
- Total size by filetype
- M4A total number of AAC & total size
- M4A total number of ALAC & total size

Depending on how well this works, I may consider using this to sort files into directories based on the output.

Answer (score 4):

You should decompose your goal into several steps easier to solve. This will have two advantages:

- It will be easier to solve,
- The resulting code will be clearer and more reusable.

The scripts below basically follows these steps:

1. **Generate raw statistic files**. An easy way is to append the file size and the file name in a temporary file named after the original file extension. So, if you have the file `/path/to/foo.mp3` which is 3000000 large, it will append `3000000 /path/to/foo.mp3` at the end of a temporary file named `mp3`.
2. **Handle specific cases**. Here it will process the temporary file `m4a` and create the two other files `m4a_aac` and `m4a_alac` based on the test you gave in the question.
3. **Generate output**. All the needed information being now available, it just has to:

   - Count the number of line in each temporary file to determine the number of file of this type,
   - Sum up each size to get the total size of files of this type.

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/sh

# This script takes the searched directory as first parameter.
# For instance: ./this-script.sh ~/Music

: ${1:?"You must pass the search directory as first parameter."}
searchdir="$1"

# Create a temporary directory
statsdir=""
trap 'rm -rf $statsdir' EXIT
statsdir=$(mktemp -d "/tmp/tmp.XXXXXXXXXX") || exit 1

# Generate one listing file per extension
awkscript='/\.[[:alnum:]]+$/ {print $0 >statsdir"/"$(NF)}'
# For Linux: stat -c "%s %n"
# For Mac: stat -f "%z %N"
find "$searchdir" -type f -exec stat -f "%z %N" {} + | \
    awk -F '.' -v statsdir="$statsdir" "$awkscript"

# Distinguish between m4a/AAC and m4a/ALAC
if [ -f "$statsdir/m4a" ]; then
    input="$statsdir/m4a"
    while IFS= read -r line; do
        filename=${line#* }
        if avprobe "$filename" 2>&1 | grep -q 'Audio: alac'; then
            echo "$line" >> "$statsdir/m4a_alac"
        else
            echo "$line" >> "$statsdir/m4a_aac"
        fi
    done < "$input"
    rm "$statsdir/m4a"
fi

# Generate and display result
{
    printf "Type Count Size\n"
    for extension in $(ls "$statsdir"); do
        count=$(wc -l "$statsdir/$extension" | cut -d ' ' -f 1)
        totalsize=$(awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}' "$statsdir/$extension")
        printf "%s %d %d\n" "$extension" "$count" "$totalsize"
    done
} | column -t
```

Comment: Thanks for this. But I'm stuck with mktemp: `NerdWork-iMac:Shell Test lowey$ ./Music\ Sort\ \&\ Count\ Script.sh ~/Music/Shell\ Test/ -dt test
usage: mktemp [-d] [-q] [-t prefix] [-u] template ...
       mktemp [-d] [-q] [-u] -t prefix`

Comment: @Lowey: `mktemp` is the recommended way to create temporary files, but sadly is not standardized :(. Your output let me guess you are using OSX, and it seems that for some reason OSX doesn't provide a default template and require one to be given as parameter. I've updated the script accordingly.

Comment: @Lowey You need to change `stat -c "%s %n"` to `stat -f "%z %N"` for OS X.

Comment: Feels like I'm getting closer, but a problem with awk now: `awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
 /\.[a-z]+$/ {print $1 >>>  >statsdir"/" <<< 
awk: illegal statement at source line 1
awk: illegal statement at source line 1
Type  Count  Size
`

Comment: @WhiteWinterWolf - I've tried, still getting the illegal statement issue with awk. It looks like it can't get the stats directory?

Comment: `awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
 /\.[[:alnum:]]+$/ {print >>>  >statsdir"/" <<< 
awk: illegal statement at source line 1
awk: illegal statement at source line 1
Type  Count  Size`

Comment: @ WhiteWinterWolf - Wow, didn't say what platform I was on. Didn't test under a different platform. Sometimes I should just stop and go to sleep. Sorry about that. Going to test this on my QNAP nas, just worried about large files in /tmp as it's on a tiny / partition.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24543/discussion-between-lowey-and-whitewinterwolf).

Comment: @Lowey: I did a bit of clean-up in the comments. Sadly I will not be able to pursue this today, however if we are lucky maybe tomorrow I could put my hand on an OS X installation.

Comment: @WhiteWinterWolf change `{print $0 >statsdir"/"$(NF)}` to `{print $0 > (statsdir"/"$(NF))}` . Also check your script, there are unbalanced quotes.

Comment: Okay, have it running now, but stuck on the read on m4a directory..... `rm "$statsdir/m4a"
fi
+ '[' -f /tmp/tmp.mpCmCjpzNt/m4a ']'
read "$statsdir/m4a"
++ read /tmp/tmp.mpCmCjpzNt/m4a`
Killed it here `^Crm -rf $statsdir
++ rm -rf /tmp/tmp.mpCmCjpzNt`

Comment: @WhiteWinterWolf @fd0 - Does the # need to be escaped in this line? `filename=${line#* }`

Comment: Voted you up because of use of the EXIT trap. Something for me to remember for general use.